# How do I use the d3 selection/join methods to change a line graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using v4.

I want to dynamically change the data for a line graph, but I can't figure out how to get the data to the `d` attribute of the `path` element.  This does not work (no line is drawn):

```
    draw_line(data) {
        let selection = this.svg.select('path.line').datum(data);
        selection.enter()
             .append('path')
             .attr('class', 'line')
             .attr('d', this.line);
        selection
            .transition(this.transition)
            .attr('d', this.line);
    }
```

The following does work, but it doesn't seem idiomatic (doesn't use `enter()`, `exit()`, etc.

```
    draw_line(data) {
        let path = this.svg.select('path.line');
        if (path.empty()) {
            this.svg
                .append('path')
                .datum(data)
                .attr('class', 'line')
                .attr('d', this.line);
        } else {
             path
                .datum(data)
                .transition(this.transition)
                .attr('d', this.line);
        }
    }
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious..?

The following shouldn't be relevant for the question, but is included for reference. 
The constructor and calling method look like:

```
class LineGraph {
    constructor(w, h, location) {
        this.margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50};
        this.outer_width = w;
        this.outer_heigth = h;
        this.width = this.outer_width - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
        this.height = this.outer_heigth - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

        this.svg = d3.select(location)
                     .append("svg")             // append the svg object to location
                       .attr("width", w)
                       .attr("height", h)
                     .append("g")               // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
                        .attr("transform", `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`);
    }

    draw(data) {
        this.transition = d3.transition()
                            .duration(2000);

        // set the ranges
        this.x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, this.width]);
        this.bottomAxis = d3.axisBottom(this.x).ticks(d3.timeWeek);

        this.y = d3.scaleLinear().range([this.height, 0]);
        this.leftAxis = d3.axisLeft(this.y);

        this.line = d3.line()
          .x(d => this.x(d.date))
          .y(d => this.y(d.value));

        // this.draw_axes(data);
        this.draw_line(data);
    }
```

and the invocation looks like:

```
let graph = new LineGraph(500, 500, '#content');
let parse_time = d3.timeParse('%d-%b-%y');
let data1 = [
    {date: parse_time('1-May-12'), value: 158.13},
    {date: parse_time('30-Apr-12'), value: 153.98},
    {date: parse_time('27-Apr-12'), value: 167.00}
];
let data2 = [
    {date: parse_time('2-May-12'), value: 242.42},
    {date: parse_time('1-May-12'), value: 158.13},
    {date: parse_time('30-Apr-12'), value: 153.98},
    {date: parse_time('27-Apr-12'), value: 167.00} 
];
graph.draw(data1.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date));

setTimeout(() => {
    graph.draw(data2.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date));
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Hey, thebjorn, since you're loading D3 library anyway why don't you use `d3.timeout` instead of `setTimeout`? It's a better function, and it has the nice feature of not running in the background. Have a look here: https://github.com/d3/d3-timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the `data()` method, `datum()` does not compute a join. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_datum):

> Unlike selection.data, this method does not compute a join and does not affect indexes or the enter and exit selections.

Also, `select` and `selectAll` behave differently regarding grouping and data propagation. You should use `selectAll`, even if you have just one line in the chart. Have a look at this table:

| Method | select() | selectAll() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Selection | selects the first element that matches the selector string | selects all elements that match the selector string |
| Grouping | Does not affect grouping | Affects grouping |
| Data propagation | Propagates data | Doesn't propagate data |

Therefore, your first snippet should be:

```
draw_line(data) {

    let selection = this.svg.selectAll('path.line')
    //'selectAll' here ----------^
        .data([data]);
        // ^--- 'data' instead of 'datum'

    selection.enter()
         .append('path')
         .attr('class', 'line')
         .attr('d', this.line);

    selection.transition(this.transition)
        .attr('d', this.line);

}
```